# UITextView clickable url opens after terminating app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextview

I am using datadetectortypes with my UITextView to be able to detect the links and navigate to the page. but the app is terminated and link opens with default safari after terminating the app. Is there any way to open the link within the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if you have web view

for example

```
  NSString *urlAddress = @"http://myurl.com";
 //Create a URL object.
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: but I wanted it in text view as much other info is also to be displayed

Comment: It's an url so it must be opened in a browser. You can't open an url in Notepad for example, can you? You can however use an NSUrlRequest, get the info you need, parse it and add the text to you textView